# new size of an image in imageView

Tags: java, android, android-imageview

I would like to know the new size of my image when it is set in an imageview.

I tried this :

```
System.out.println("Imagesize 1 w:" + imageView.getDrawable().getIntrinsicWidth()+" h "+imageView.getDrawable().getIntrinsicHeight());
System.out.println("Imagesize 2  w:" +loadedImage.getWidth()+ " h " +loadedImage.getHeight());
```

xml1 of imageView:

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
```

I have this result

```
Imagesize 1 w:400 h 577
Imagesize 2 w:400 h 577
```

xml2 of imageView:

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Same result:

```
Imagesize 1 w:400 h 577
Imagesize 2 w:400 h 577
```

Obviously my image is not displayed in my screen with the same size in case of xml1 and xml2. I guess when I getWidth or getHeight it is the real size of the image, but I would like the size of the image displayed on my screen.

Any ideas?

Update 1:

I forgot to say that loadedImage is the bitmap of my image

Update 2:

xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="1dip" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/descr_image"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/loading"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/webView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the size of screen objects after they have been created you need to use a view observer like so:

```
ViewTreeObserver viewTreeObserver = YOURLAYOUT.getViewTreeObserver();
if (viewTreeObserver.isAlive()) {
viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
      public void onGlobalLayout() {
         YOURLAYOUT.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
         //do some things
         //YOURLAYOUT.getWidth() should give a correct answer
      }
});
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried your solution and I have the same result w:536, h:846 for all my different images..

Comment: What is the actual size of the image? Might be worth looking into the setAdjustViewBounds(boolean adjustViewBounds) method of ImageView.

Comment: I have several different images, so different size, but the example I put in this post is : real size : 400*577

Comment: does your xml1 of imageView have a parent that has a width and height of wrap_content?

Comment: If I add this setAdjustViewBounds(true) how would it be helpful to know the size of my image?

Comment: Why are you using imageView.getDrawable().getIntrinsicWidth()? WHen you try using the ViewObserver, are you using imageView.getWidth()?

Comment: yes I did it, that my first comment "..the same result w:536, h:846 for all my different images..". I tried your way, and the two way in my post

Comment: In fact when I change android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" to wrap_content, your solution works. Thank you very much :)! Could you just explain me why I need a ViewTreeObserver?

Comment: ViewTreeObserver is called when the view tree is loaded. All the properties (width, height, etc) are inherited etc, and therefore you can get image size.